# symmetric ranges of curve division on an oloid

Tags: geometry, parametric, symmetry, curves

taken from wikipedia , I drew an [Oloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oloid) by using the functions

[image]          with

[image];

[image];

and

[image] with

[image];

[image];

If I use any equal spaced range of t(x) on [image];  I will end up with an unequal range t(y), which looks like this:

[image]

My goal is to have a symmetric, spacing on both of the curves like in this model:

[image]

I can only remap the values of t(x).

What function do I need to apply on the range t(x) to get a symmetric curve division also on  t(y) ?
Any expert out there?
Please help.

Best,

Phillip

Comment: Let $t\in[\pi,3\pi/2]$.

Comment: Hi Michael Hoppe,
I am not sure I understand. 
This is not so much about what range the elements are in, but how to apply a function on them so the entire arrangement is “harmonic”.  
I am not sure if this is right, but I guess, what I am looking for is how to make the midpoints of the connecting lines equidistant. 
Can you follow me?
Thanks,
Phillip

Comment: For what I have tested so far, a parabolic distribution comes quite close... Any ideas?

Comment: Too hard? Too simple? Not understandable? Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

I do not have the ability to prove the non-existence of a solution to the OP's question, but I can offer justification for the existing equations. This should give some insight.

While they contain obvious singularities, the equations shown by the OP look to have originated loosely from Dirnbock and Stachel 1997 where there is no proof of (specifically) equations (2) and (4).

http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jgg/jgg01_05/jgg0113.pdf

My proof of equations (2) and (4) follows. An inversion is required to get from point U to point T with a further inversion in going from T to V.

The spatial separation of points is not symmetric but the paths between them are reversible.

I provide this analysis and an alternative parametrization here:

https://github.com/logicmonkey/surfaces/blob/master/OloidPoints/OloidPoints.pdf

## Inversion with Respect to a Circle

Point A
  on the unit circle centred at the origin O
  lies on the tangent line that crosses the x-axis at point P
  as shown below. The point P'
  is the inverse of P
  with respect to the circle. Similarly, P
  is the inverse of P'
 . If the x coordinate of P'
  is $\cos\left(t\right)$
 , then the x coordinate of P
  is $\frac{1}{cos(t)}$
 . This bidirectional relationship is exploited in the following sections.
[image: Inversion with respect to a circle]

## Parametrization using Transcendental Functions

Points U
  and V
  lie on unit circles centred at $C_{U}=(0,-\frac{1}{2})$
  and $C_{V}=(0,\frac{1}{2})$
  respectively as shown below. U
  and V
  correspond to points A
  and B
  in Dirnbock and Stachel's paper of 1997.

$$U\left(t\right)=\left[\sin\left(t\right),-\frac{1}{2}-\cos\left(t\right),0\right]$$

The triangle T'UV
  is formed by the joining line UV
  and the intersection point T'
  of the tangent lines through U
  and V
 . Point T'
  is also the inverse of point $T_{U}=(0,-\frac{1}{2}-\cos\left(t\right))$
 .

By inversion with respect to the circle, the distance $C_{U}T'$
  is$$|C_{U}T'|=\frac{1}{\cos\left(t\right)}$$

[image: First step U to T']
[image: Next step T' to V]

For simplicity, the circle centred at $C_{V}$
  is rotated from yz into the xy plane. Since the circle centres are distance 1 apart, length $T'C_{V}$
  is therefore

$$|T'C_{V}|=1+\frac{1}{\cos\left(t\right)}$$
 $T_{V}$
  is the inverse of T'
  with respect to the upper circle, making the displacement along the y axis

$$|C_{V}T_{V}|=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\cos\left(t\right)}}=\frac{\cos\left(t\right)}{1+\cos\left(t\right)}$$

By Pythagoras, the squared distance of V
  to the y axis is $$|VT_{V}|^{2}=1-\frac{\cos^{2}\left(t\right)}{\left(1+\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}}=\frac{1+2\cos\left(t\right)}{\left(1+\cos\left(t\right)\right)^{2}}$$

Rotating back into the yz plane it follows that V has the parametrization

$$V\left(t\right)=\left[0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos\left(t\right)}{1+\cos\left(t\right)},\pm\frac{\sqrt{1+2\cos\left(t\right)}}{1+\cos\left(t\right)}\right]$$

Comment: Your treatment is so lengthy that it is difficult to see how it partly answers the Question.  A summary ("executive summary") at top of your post would improve the readability.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll add some more text to make it a bit shorter for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting into this, logicmonkey , since it has been out there for a while and I did not believe there would someone still looking at this. I have to go with hardmath, saying that ,yes, it is difficult for me to follow, but most likely of my poor math skills though. I will try to spend more time in getting it all and grabbing the essence of your conclusions. Thanks a lot so far already.

Comment: The geometric side is simple, but the algebraic side isn't,

Comment: The geometric side is simple, but the algebraic side isn't, We need to get from U to V via T'. U to T' is one function 'f'. T to V is another function 'g'. Then we need the inverse function f' and g'. Inverse functions are notoriously difficult. And we've got two of them. I think I've successfully inverted my funtions (see the linked PDF in the tl;dr) but I think it would be difficult to find a parametrization on one arc that maps back to a similar one on the other.

Comment: I will play with taking the log of the parameter variable t  before feeding it into the forward functions. That should make the output a bit more evenly spaced. After that it would be 'suck it and see' with numerical methods to find a nice result. Try and follow my derivation for V(t) - it's quite pleasing in itself. Enjoy!